# How can I pass these values as a reference instead?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Grid that gets populated with a `List<VersionedFile>`. The user can select any number of rows and have the application perform some sort of SVN function on them; add, commit, remove etc.

Currently, after the user modifies a file, the list does not immediately reflect the status change. They need to re-query the directory and this can take a while. I'm working on fixing up the code to immediately update the UI as soon as the action succeeds.

So I've got this code that iterates over the selected rows in the grid and returns each row as a `VersionedFile` object and throws it into a list. Then I iterate over this list, perform the Add/Remove/ action and set that iteration's `Status` property to the appropriate value. However, the UI does not change.

UI:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        var vfiles = GetVFiles();
        _presenter.SvnAdd(vfiles);

        Cursor = DefaultCursor;
    }

    private List<VersionedFile> GetVFiles()
    {
        var files = new List<VersionedFile>();

        foreach (var key in gdcSVNDefaultView.GetSelectedRows())
            files.Add((VersionedFile)gdcSVNDefaultView.GetRow(key));

        return files;
    }
```

Presenter:

```
    public void SvnAdd(List<VersionedFile> files)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var numExceptions = 0;

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                _helper.SvnAdd(file.Path);
                file.Status = SvnStatus.Added;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(ex);

                if (numExceptions < 10)
                    sb.AppendLine(file.Path);
                numExceptions++;
            }                
        }

        ShowResult("Added", sb.ToString(), numExceptions, files.Count);
    }
```

The code compiles and runs perfectly fine. `vfiles` has the proper data in it. But my UI doesn't get updated until I manually refresh the grid. I'm assuming somewhere along the line SvnAdd simply receives an object of equal value, rather than a reference to the actual data that is that row in the grid.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Would it be bad practice to pass SvnAdd the rows themselves, rather than a list of objects built from the rows?

Comment: if this is a sync problem, try an updatepanel..http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-trigger-an-updatepanel-refresh-from-a-dropdownlist-control

Comment: @foxtrotZulu winforms

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building a new list in `GetVFiles`, return the actual `DataSource` of the grid so that it's modified directly:

```
private List<VersionedFile> GetVFiles()
{
    return (List<VersionedFile>)gdcSVNDefaultView.DataSource;
}
```

Comment: Then would I just determine the selected rows from this List in my method that performs the actual Svn operation?

Comment: @sab669, use the [`IsSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.isselected(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the grid and pass in the current index of the row you're working on to determine if it's selected.

Comment: Could you expand your answer please? Since the SvnAdd method is in a completely separate class, I don't understand how i'd be able to utilize IsSelected to determine anything about the rows. SvnAdd is basically now just being passed some List with 20K items in it.

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem on data being updated on a single thread. Once data is updated, invoke the notifications back to the grid on the UI Thread. This is done with a BindingSource. First, create a class that inherits BindingSource and use it as the datasource of your grids. Set any DataTable as datasource of a BindingSource.

In your BindingSource class add this:

```
protected override void OnListChanged(ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
 var control = Form.ActiveForm;
if (control != null && control.InvokeRequired)
    control.Invoke(new Action<ListChangedEventArgs>(OnListChanged), e);
else
{
    base.OnListChanged(e);
}
}
```